# How set image to data grid view cell after data binding?

Tags: c#, image, datagridview, cell, formatting

I have problem with  adding  image to  DGV cell  after  data binding.

this is my code:

```
                DataTable tab = conn.searchData(searchTmp);
              bindingSource1.DataSource = tab;
              DGV.AllowUserToAddRows = false;

              DGV.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);                
              //dont show this colls
              DGV.Columns["zId"].Visible = false;
              DGV.Columns["tId"].Visible = false;
              DGV.Columns["tId2"].Visible = false;

              DataGridViewImageColumn co = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
              System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
              thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
              System.IO.Stream file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Resources.Tx1[k].gif");
              System.IO.Stream file2 = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("MyApp.Resources.Tx2[k].gif");
```

// and other  for  all column --  first grey row

```
              Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file);
              co.Image = bmp;

              DataGridViewImageColumn img = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
              Image image = bmp;
              img.Image = image;
              DGV.Columns.Add(img);
              img.HeaderText = "Image";
              img.Name = "img";
```

Data table is result from databases, 
in first coll i have TeX expression -- I want generate images for this expression  with "MimeTex.dll", I know  how do this but I don't know how replace this TeX expression with   image,
on the screen is my raw DGV,  without images.

on last six lines  I have a part of code  for add new column because I testing and trying how  replace  first row columns text (header row)  with static images from apps resource without success...

Any idea?
TIA
screen : 
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?66fe2964fe.jpg

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
  DataGridViewImageColumn ic= new DataGridViewImageColumn();
  ic.HeaderText = "Img";
  ic.Image = null;
  ic.Name = "cImg";
  ic.Width = 100;
  DGV.Columns.Add(ic);


  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV.Rows)
  {
    DataGridViewImageCell cell = row.Cells[1] as DataGridViewImageCell;
    cell.Value = (System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.Icon_delete;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

simply you can write:
DGV.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value = Properties.Resources.Icon_delete;