# C# LoadData , Convert column to image in dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need when load dataGridView status[status] column convert to image and show image ,
The column status = 1 or 0 and i need if 1 show ok.png and if 0 show no.png

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            SetConnection();
            sql_con.Open();
            sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
            string CommandText = "select id[code] ,status[status], url[url] from  db";
            DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText, sql_con);
            DS.Reset();
            DB.Fill(DS);
            DT = DS.Tables[0];
            dataGridView.DataSource = DT;
            dataGridView.Columns["code"].Visible = false;
            sql_con.Close();
        }
```

anyone can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: you can use onDataItemBound and give the image

Comment: You can find possible answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876996/how-set-image-to-data-grid-view-cell-after-data-binding

Comment: datatype invalid error show !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CellFormatting` event of `DataGridView` as follow:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            var dt = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > e.RowIndex && dt.Columns.Count > e.ColumnIndex)
            {
                var value = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[e.RowIndex][e.ColumnIndex]);
                if (value == 0)
                    e.Value = Image.FromFile(@"C:\No.png"); // Here you can provide your own path of No.png image
                if (value == 1)
                    e.Value = Image.FromFile(@"C:\OK.png"); // Here you can provide your own path of Ok.png image

            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
Instead of Auto-Generating columns, create columns in `DataGridView` as shown in image:

[image]

Comment: Hi , i used  e.Value = Properties.Resources.invalid; and add using System.Drawing; but show in rows <System.Drawing.Bitmap>

Comment: I tried with your code, it's showing the images from resources also. I have used `DataGridViewImageColumn` for Status field, have you used the same?

Comment: dear Status field load from data base how converted in DataGridView ;  string CommandText = "select id[code] ,status[status], url[url] from  db"; dataGridView.DataSource = DT;

Comment: When you auto-generate columns, `DataGridView` creates columns as per the type of the column in the data source. So you shouldn't auto-generate the columns, instead create columns in `DataGridView` on your own. I have edited my answer and shared a screenshot of columns I have created in `DataGridView`.